# Delayed Spring Boot application startup

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot 3 application with PostgreSQL and if my database that is in Docker is not ready yet, it does not start the application, how can I configure it so that the application starts even without a connection to the database, or that it keeps restarting until that there is a stable connection?

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Comment: Seems not that complicated: https://deinum.biz/2020-06-30-Wait-for-database-startup/, thx @mdeinum :)

Comment: Thanks for linking to my blog, glad it (finally?) helped someone.